# How to dynamically create parameters' names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function that I want to make more generic:

```
function addRow2(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#dataTable").append(row);
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.param1 + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.param2 + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.param3 + "</td>"));
}
```

I tried the following approach:

```
function addRow1(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#dataTable").append(row);
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        var marker = [];
        marker[i] = 'rowData.param'+i;
        alert(marker[i]);
        row.append($("<td>" + marker[i] + "</td>"));
    }
}
```

However, instead of the values of `rowData.param1`...`3` it prints "rowData.param1", "rowData.param1" and "rowData.param1".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to access an object property by string name like this:

```
marker[i] = rowData['param' + i];
```

As a side note, you are creating a new array each iteration and storing your property name as the `i`th element of that array.  You could more simply use a variable:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    var marker = rowData['param' + i];
    alert(marker);
    row.append($("<td>" + marker + "</td>"));
}
```

Or a one-liner:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData['param' + i] + "</td>"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.each` to get all the properties from rawData, this way you don't have to rely on `param1, param2` and use meaningfull object properties.

```
function addRow2(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#dataTable").append(row);
    $.each(rowData, function (prop, value) {
        row.append($("<td>" + value + "</td>"));
    });
}
```

Comment: What is 'r' in this context?

Comment: not a good idea if you want to iterate over the keys in a particular order. Could be good if order doesn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you creating an array? Can't your code be simplified to:

```
function addRow1(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#dataTable").append(row);
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData['param' + i] + "</td>"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the point is to print the data in `param[1,2,3]` and not printing that.

Comment: No - If you look at the original code each iteration of the loop re-creates the array. I see now he is trying to get the data out of the rowData though. So really $('<td>'+ rowData['param' + i] + '</td>') is what he wants. Still no reason to create an array.

Comment: If that's really what he wanted... the code he wrote exactly does that and the question here wouldn't be needed.